# Inserting 2 Divs inside 1 Div(one on the left side and other on the right side)

Tags: html, css

I'm a noob at CSS and I was playing with CSS and DIVS, everything was going well until I decided put 2 Divs inside of one. I can put ONE div inside of another, but when I put 2 it just bugs.
[I could put the green Div inside of yellow div but not the cyan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b66Y1.png)

Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="style_divs.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="table">
    <div id="year">2017</div>
    <div id="month">
        <div id="previousMonth">Previous</div>
        <div id="nextMonth">Next</div>
        January
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#table{
    width:25%;
    height:50%;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#year{
    width:100%;
    height:10%;
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
#month{
    width:100%;
    height:10%;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#previousMonth{
    width:12%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: 0%;
    text-align: center;
}

#nextMonth{
    width:12%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: cyan;
    margin-left: 88%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `float` on the `divs`?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Wow thanks. I feel very stupid right now.

Comment: My question was about how to put 2 divs inside of a div. @OkeTega suggested me doing with float property and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to use the #previousmonth float:left and #nextMonth float:right

You should not use the margin feature to achieve this below is the corrected two styles using the float command

```
#previousMonth{
width:12%;
float:left;
height:100%;
background-color: green;
text-align: center;
}

#nextMonth{
width:12%;
height:100%;
float:right;
background-color: cyan;
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
height:500px;
width:600px;
}
#table{
width:50%;
height:70%;
background-color: red;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#year{
width:100%;
height:10%;
background-color: blue;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;

}
#month{
width:100%;
height:10%;
background-color: yellow;
margin: 0 auto;
}

/*wrapped them in div so they can be one group*/
#pager{
height:100%;/*tells the pager to take 100% of parent's height(month)*/
}
#pager div{/*tells the child divs of pager to have same properties*/
display:inline-block;/*this will display contents side by side one another*/
width:12%;
height:100%;
}

#previousMonth{
background-color: green;/*assign properties that are unique to the child*/
}

#nextMonth{
background-color: cyan;
float:right; /*  this will make it float to right */
}
#monthname{
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="table">
    <div id="year">2017</div>
    <div id="month">
      <div id="pager">
        <div id="previousMonth">Previous</div>
        <div id="nextMonth">Next</div>
      </div> 
        <div id="monthname">January<div/>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

I have tinkered with your codes a bit. You need to tell the element what to do. Also, try not to wrote same codes to children since they will inherit the parent's properties. Pressing F12 will tell you which properties the element has when rendered. Hope this helps. Good luck and happy coding.